# Doubt related to Symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a real symmetric matrix.
Which of the following are true.

(a) If $ A^k=I_n$ for some positive integer $k$ then $A^2=I$

(b) If $ A^k=0_n$ for some positive integer $k$ then $A^2=0_n$

My approach: (b) Given $A^k=I_n \implies $ minimal polynomial(say $m(x))$ should divide the annihilating polynomial that is $m_\lambda(x) | \lambda^k-1 $ so minimal polynomial is product of linear factors. Hence matrix is diagonalizable and by definition it is nilpotent matrix so $A$ must be zero which implies $A^2=0_n.$

But for part (a) How to prove or disprove it Idont have any idea.
Please check part b and suggest something for part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attacked (b) with diagonalisation, which is often the right approach when you have a symmetric matrix. That works with (a) as well. Let's assume that diagonalisation has already been done, and we're working with a diagonal matrix.

If $A^k = I$, then each of the diagonal entries must fulfill $x^k = 1$. And among the reals, there are only two numbers that do that: $\pm 1$. Therefore all diagonal entries are either $1$ or $-1$, and therefore $A^2$ must be the identity matrix.